# Ruler/Protractor tool - change text color

Tags: customization, theme

I use Blender 2.78 . How can I change the text color for the [Ruler/protractor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/ruler_and_protractor.html) tool results in the blender user reference ( theme), e.g. shown below.

[image: screenshot-ruler-protractor-tool]

Comment: I added screenshot of the text I assume you'd like to change; if it's not this one feel free to [edit] the question with your own. As to customization I have found only one way to do that, in User Prefs > Theme Space Settings > text option will change it

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, but in user prefs I only managed to control the color text of the themes windows but not the dimension text color. can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: [The property changed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Lls.gif) is what I meant. Note that it might affect some other text color in 3D view (I didn't find though)

Comment: Hi, Found the Text color control thanks. will it be too mach to ask how I can change the back ground tor this text?

Comment: It's totally ok to ask it but I don't really know the answer regarding the built-in Ruler. You can customize colors with MeasureIt addon, [BA thread](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?371788-Add-on-v1-6-MeasureIt-measurement-tools), it's bundled with Blender now so just enable it. Controls to add measurements in the Toolshelf, to customize colors - in the Properties shelf.